# How to submit a form and get data from google map marker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

Using [Angular google map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) plugin. I am trying to submit a form in google map marker infoWindow and read the data in my controller.

I am not able to detect the click on "Ok" in my controller.

```
$scope.register = function()
{
     console.log('register clicked');
}
```

I am not able to see this log print.

```html
<ui-gmap-google-map >
                <ui-gmap-marker >
                    <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" show="true" closeClick="closeClick()">
                        <form class="form "  >
                                <label >Name</label>&nbsp;
                                <input  type="text" ng-model="name"/>

                                <label>Place</label>&nbsp;
                                <input  type="text" ng-model="place"/>

                                <button type="submit"  ng-click="register()">Ok</button>
                                 <button type="button"  ng-click="closeClick()">Cancel</button>  
                        </form>
                    </ui-gmap-window>
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @devlincarnate I have updated the question, basically I have a form in infoWindow of marker but I am not able to submit that form.

Comment: probably that `ui-gmap-marker` has its own scope and can not access your scope, or you do not have your function in the controller that encloses your ui-gmap-google-map...

Comment: @niklas I am not aware of marker having a separate scope or controller, can you explain more about it?

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers? Have you accomplished it in another way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it using [Compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) Service of Angularjs.

Just assign an ID to the popup and compile it.

var pp = angular.element(document.querySelector('#id_poup_element'));

$compile(pp)($scope);

Happy to answer any queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `ui-gmap-window` content is in another scope. 
Suposing that you have the `register()` function in your main controller, if you want fo access it from map-window, you need to call it using `$parent` twice:

```
<button ng-click="$parent.$parent.register()">Ok</button>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wI8Qe3eZR7FQJUfO4Msx?p=preview), where you can see it working.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use $parent.$parent as you are directly referencing a parent scope, modify your code so the controller you are using is in scope of the google map UI, My answer maybe vague but will help you get some clues - make it so that your function gets called  from within the scope of the map controller

```
.controller("someController", function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

    });
     $scope.register = function(){
        // do something
      };
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's fine, and obviously better as long as a new controller can be created. I just tried to explain why the OP case is not working. Thansk for the advise :)